# Generate background and text classes based on color variables

Tags: css, sass

I am looking to utilize a SASS Rules (@mixin, @extend, etc.) and/or control directives (@if, @for, @each, etc.) to generate classes for the color variables that I have defined.

Below is an example of what I am using currently, but I know that I can further simplify this to make it significantly less redundant.

```
// Colors
$navy: #37455a;
$blue: #abbdd3;
$cyan: #a3d9cb;
$peach: #ff9d7a;

// Backgrounds
.bg-navy{
  background: $navy;
}

.bg-blue{
  background: $blue;
}

.bg-cyan{
  background: $cyan;
}

.bg-peach{
  background: $peach;
}

// Text
.text-navy{
  color: $navy;
}

.text-blue{
  color: $blue;
}

.text-cyan{
  color: $cyan;
}

.text-peach{
  color: $peach;
}
```

I have tried a few different methods, but I always run into conflicts with mapping.  I want to preserve the mapped variable in the object to use outside of these functions.  This is what I have come up with so far:

```
// Colors for use in other partials
$navy: #37455a;
$blue: #abbdd3;
$cyan: #a3d9cb;
$peach: #ff9d7a;

// Mapped colors used for generating classes (Duplicated unfortunately)
$colors: (
  $navy: #37455a;
  $blue: #abbdd3;
  $cyan: #a3d9cb;
  $peach: #ff9d7a;
)

// Background class definition
@mixin bg{
  .bg-#{$color}{
    background: $color;
  }
}

// Text class definition
@mixin text{
  .text-#{$color}{
    color: $color;
  }
}

// Background class generation
@each $color in $colors{
  @include bg($color);
}

// Text class generation
@each $color in $colors{
  @include text($color);
}
```

While what I have above does not work, it's closer to what I am trying do accomplish.  Has anybody solved for what I am attempting to do here?  Any insight would be much appreciated as well!

Comment: thank you, i've had this same problem but didn't know how to put my problem in words

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One mixin to do it all!

```
$navy: #37455a;
$blue: #abbdd3;
$cyan: #a3d9cb;
$peach: #ff9d7a;

$colors: (
  navy: $navy,
  blue: $blue,
  cyan: $cyan,
  peach: $peach
);

@mixin gen-props($prefix, $property) {
  @each $color-name, $color in $colors {
    .#{$prefix}-#{$color-name} {
      #{$property}: $color
    }
  }
}

@include gen-props('text', 'color');
@include gen-props('bg', 'background');
```